# Mysql changing the collation from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8mb4_bin

Tags: mysql, collation, utf8mb4

One of my columns has special characters like "Ψ" which latin1_swedish_ci does not seem to support. To handle such cases I tried switching the collation to utf8mb4_bin for the one column. But when converting the data i get:

```
Query error:
#1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xE4' for column 'title' at row 18
```

Note: I'm using phpmyadmin to change it. Why am i getting this error? I thought utf8mb4_bin could support it?

Comment: [Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html).

Comment: "When converting"  -- Can you back off on the conversion?  What SQL was performed?  There are several possible ways -- most cause trouble.  You may have to perform the proper SQL rather than depending on a UI to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in for a rocky road.  Hex `E4` has nothing to do with `Psi`.  Where did it come from?

Do `SELECT title, HEX(title) ...` on some title that has a non-Ascii character in it.

The UTF-8 encoding for psi is two hex characters `CEA8`.

`E4`, when interpreted as `latin1` represents `ä`.  Does that make any sense?

- The column needs to be changed to `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).  But there is a right way to do that and a way that messes things up worse.  Let's see that HEX before discussing which is right.
- The `VARIABLEs` that control what encoding the *client* is using.  There are multiple settings that need to change when switching encodings.

More references:

- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases
- [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

No charset maps E4 to Psi:

```
cp1250, cp1257, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5, latin7  25 24
                                                     'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaä'
                                        cp852  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicań'
                                        cp850  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaõ'
                                        macce  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaš'
                                          hp8  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicað'
                                        greek  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaδ'
                                      keybcs2  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no NausicaΣ'
                                       cp1251  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaд'
                                 koi8r, koi8u  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no NausicaД'
                                        cp866  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaф'
                                     armscii8  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no NausicaՊ'
                                       hebrew  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaה'
                                       cp1256  25 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaن'
                                       tis620  26 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaไ'
                                      geostd8  26 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausicaჰ'
                                     macroman  26 24 'Kaze no Tani no Nausica‰'
```

So, I worry that two mistakes have been made.  Do you have another example of mangled text?

Latin1 *cannot* handle Greek letters.  Nor Cyrillic.  Nor Chinese.  Etc.  So, `ä` is "correct"?  (I have been chasing how to get between E4 and Psi.)

So you should probably convert to utf8mb4.

```
ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

will convert *all* the text columns in table `t`.

To change just one column:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN c VARCHAR(...)
     CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

It must contain all the other stuff you have not (eg, NULL or NOT NULL).

Comment: When i do `select title, HEX(title) from tablename` I get a bunch of rows. The title that contains `ä` has the hex(title) of `4B617A65206E6F2054616E69206E6F204E617573696361E4`

Comment: @LTM - I added to my Answer.  utf8mb4 will support Psi, not not as E4.  We need to find a safe way to convert your text to utf8mb4; I don't (yet) see a _safe_ way.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding here. But I'm not looking a charset that maps E4 to Psi.

Basically what happened is that originally my default collation was latin1_swedish_ci. This worked for me. I was able to insert `Kaze no Tani no Nausicaä` with errors. But when I tried to insert a title with `Ψ` into the `latin1_swedish_ci` column, typeORM complained with an error and `Ψ` was not inserted .I thought maybe that is because `latin1_swedish_ci` cannot represent  `Ψ`. So from there, in order to insert `Ψ` in the db I tried to change the collation to utf8mb4.This resulted in the error in my post.

Comment: So what I'm looking for is basically two things: 1. a charset that will allow me to have both `Ψ` and most other types of characters. 2. a way to change my  latin1_swedish_ci to that charset/collation. My data is not corrupted (to my knowledge). When you said  `Hex E4 has nothing to do with Psi` I agree. My issue isn't that I want E4 to be `Ψ`. I just want a charset and a way to convert my title column to that charset.

Comment: @LTM - Yes, I barked up a different tree.  I updated my Answer.

Comment: @LTM - There is at least one Greek character set, but it may not also include a-double-dot.  So I don't recommend that.  utf8mb4 covers all character sets; it is the "right" way to go.  If done incorrectly, `E4` will cause trouble.  Hmmm...  Maybe i still have not correctly answered your Question.

Comment: Running your command seems to fix the issue. I tried adding both `Ψ` and `ä` and some other symbols like ☆ to the db and it works - no error! Thanks for the help!